# Array does not get filled

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-sql

I have a little function.

Basically its doing a WebSQL search for Users that have birthday at a specific Date.

**My problem** is that it logs the users with `console.log(user)` and I can see an output, but somehow the users array is empty although I push the users to it `users.push(user)`.

For me it seems like the array `users` is not accessible in the code (but I do not get any errors)

**What do I wrong?** Thanks!

```
compare_dates_with_users: function(dates){
    var users = [];
    var dates_string = this.prepare_dates_for_query(dates);

    this.get_database().transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday IN (" + dates_string.join(', ') + "); ", [], function(tx, results){

            var len = results.rows.length, i;
              for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var user = results.rows.item(i);
                    user.f_date = true;

                    console.log(user);

                    users.push(user);
              }

        });
    });

    return users;
},
```

Comment: Is it an asyncronous task? `users` will get returned before the transaction happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database execution is an async task. You need to use a callback when the SQL execution is complete, giving back the users array. It would then be filled.

The function exits and returns users before the database execution is completed, so users is still an empty array.

---

Edit

As someone noted, you can also use a promise.

Example using callback:

```
compare_dates_with_users: function(dates, callback){
    var users = [];
    var dates_string = this.prepare_dates_for_query(dates);

    this.get_database().transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthday IN (" + dates_string.join(', ') + "); ", [], function(tx, results){

            var len = results.rows.length, i;
              for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var user = results.rows.item(i);
                    user.f_date = true;

                    console.log(user);

                    users.push(user);
              }

            callback(users);
        });
    });
 },
```

Calling the function:

```
compare_dates_with_users(dates, function(users){
    //Users is now populated
    console.log(users);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on Web SQL, but it seems as you are executing the callback function that is asynchronous. That would mean that the line

```
return users;
```

is reached before any of the callbacks (and pushes) are called. This causes the result to be an empty array even if though each user item is not empty or null.

The best approach here would be to have your own callback defined and execute it with full users array as the result of your query.